# Assign field of class in another method

Tags: java

Declaring field of class via sending it as parameter to non static method in another one is The main problem. In one method, I am sending field of class as parameter to another one to check it and assign it to new instance. But, it seems instead of call-by-reference, it calls it with call-by-value. How can I fix it?

```
class Foo{
    private volatile static Set field;

    void bar(){
        loadSet(Foo.field);
        .... <------ at that line after loadSet field is null
    }

    void loadSet(Set instance){
      if(instance == null){
           instance = Operation.getInstance(); // <--- getInstance returns new instance
      }
    }
}
```

I do not want loadSet and bar methods to be static due to performance issue, i.e. not violating pure parallelization.

I know addAll method Set but in my real code, I am using third-party-library and it returns an instance type IPos. Also, IPos does not have clone, copy or addAll method. I have used Set for simplicity purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass reference to the field. You can pass only reference to an object stored in the field. In `null` case it doesn't point to anything. The best I could suggest without changing your approach is

```
class Foo{
  private volatile static Set field;

  void bar(){
      Foo.field = loadSet(Foo.field);
      .... <------ at that line after loadSet field is null
  }

  Set loadSet(Set instance){
    if(instance == null){
         return Operation.getInstance(); // <--- getInstance returns new instance
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better and cleaner approach would be to encapsulate the 'field' field.

```
  class Foo{
    private static Set field;

    private static Set field() { // <- may need to change to protected or public of default visibility depending on your use case
      if (field == null) {
        // Double-checked locking works perfectly, no need to mark 'field' volatile.
        synchronized(Foo.class) {
          if (field == null) {
            field = Operation.getInstance();
          }
        }
      }
      return field;
    }

    void bar(){
      // use Foo.field() everywhere instead of Foo.field;
    }
  }
```